# Is there a way to avoid crashes due to Firebase/Google dependency updates?

Tags: ios, google-maps, firebase, google-maps-sdk-ios

Whenever Firebase/Google Maps update their SDKs, my app's workspace fails to run and the existing build on my phone crashes. The errors are usually 'No such module Firebase' or 'No such module Gooogle Maps.' To solve this, I run `pod deintegrate` and `pod install`, then reinstall the app on my phone.

My app was just rejected from the app store, so I viewed my workspace. This error was showing up, so I cleared it. Everything ran smoothly on my device and the simulators. The app reviewer mentioned a crash and the crash log says the app took too long to load, so it terminated. Exact same thing would happened on my phone whenever Firebase/Google Maps changed their pods. The reviewer's crash logs also have this line: `Thread 20 name:  com.google.Maps.LabelingBehavior`

Is there a way to avoid device crashes when Firebase/Google Maps dependencies need to be updated? I would have to do a version update of my app whenever Google simply relabels something, and all users of the app would experience crashing until they update. If it helps, the termination error from their logs is `Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0x5`.

Comment: Updating shouldn't cause crashes. If it does, report a reproducible example at https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues. However, there is no need to update if the old versions are working fine for you.  Why not just keep using the original pods.

Comment: The old versions don't work, that's the issue I'm seeing. The workspace fails to run and existing builds on my device crash. I'll report it, but I'd like to see if someone is familiar with my problem first. Thanks for the link.